# Constructor inheritance in C++. Derived class's default constructor is not being called

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, c++17

I have this sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor of A" << '\n';
    }
    A(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Inside the constructor of A with one int argument" << '\n';
    }
};

class B : A
{
    using A::A;
public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor of B" << '\n';
    }
};


int main()
{
    B b(12);

    std::cout << "End of main";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Inside the constructor of A with one int argument
End of main
```

My expectation would be for the output to be like this:

```
Inside the constructor of A with one int argument
Default constructor of B
End of main
```

I'm basing this on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) which claims: "If overload resolution selects one of the inherited constructors when initializing an object of such derived class, then the Base subobject from which the constructor was inherited is initialized using the inherited constructor, and all other bases and members of Derived are initialized as if by the defaulted default constructor (default member initializers are used if provided, otherwise default initialization takes place). The entire initialization is treated as a single function call: initialization of the parameters of the inherited constructor is sequenced-before initialization of any base or member of the derived object."

Am I misreading this somehow? Is the default derived constructor not meant to be called after an inherited constructor?

Comment: "...are initialized as if by the defaulted default constructor" means as if, it doesnt say that the default constructor is called

Comment: In that cppreference quote, what exactly makes you think that the `B` default constructor would be called? `B` is not a base or a member of `B`.

Comment: *and all other bases and members of Derived are initialized as if by the defaulted default constructor* does not mean it calls the default constructor, it means the class will behave **as if** it did.  IIRC the compiler synthesizes a constructor for you using the base class one as a start.

Comment: Thank you for the input, so there is a generated constructor using the base class one as a start, and the rest of the generation is I suppose meant to initialize all other members, i.e. if I added a member variable:
int i =32;
There would be some code to write 32 to i after the base class constructor is called.
If I understand correctly.

Is there any way to get my expected behaviour in c++ though?

Comment: You can easily get the behavior you want by writing a `B(int)` constructor that calls your `A(int)` constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you Nathan, it's not exactly the behaviour I want since I want my default constructor to run after any of the base class constructors. So hypothetically if A were to have like 15 different constructors all with different signatures, I'd like my default constructor to be called after any of them.

Comment: @NathanOliver As for what in that sentence made me think that. I probably just didn't understand the sentence and made this assumption. I think I understand now.

Comment: "Thank you Nathan, it's not exactly the behaviour I want since I want my default constructor to run after any of the base class constructors." base class constructor is called first

Comment: @Horace In that case I would just give all of you class members a default initializer.  Then those values will be used from the constructor the compiler creates from the inherited constructor.  If you need even more code to do some post processing then you might want to look into using a factory function to create your objects.

Comment: @NathanOliver Fair enough. I'm using the Qt6 library and I just wanted to inherit a QtWidget and provide it with some defaults. 

If you can imagine for example I just want to set a default font and a little icon for a UI element. It would be so neat if I could've provided 1 default constructor with 5 lines of code where all of that would happen and I'd be free to construct the Class using any of the provided constructors.

Comment: You could try out a perfect forwarding constructor like `template <typename... Args> B(Args&&... args) : A(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { /* do your defaulting stuff here */ }`

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for the suggestion! That looks very promising although I do not understand it quite yet. Looks exactly like what I'm looking for though.

Comment: It uses a variadic template to take in any amount of parameters and then forwards them to the `A` class.  One issue with this is it wont do implicit conversions so it might not work it all cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quote says:

> [...] are initialized as if by the defaulted default constructor [...]

A defaulted default constructor would be

```
struct foo {
     foo() = default;
     //        defaulted       because = default;
     // default constrcutor    because can be called without arguments
};
```

And the quote explains that members, bases subobjects etc. are initializes "as if" by such a defaulted default constructor. The quote does not say anywhere that a default constructor is actually called. Moreover, your constructor is not a defaulted default constructor. Its a default constructor, but with a custom implementation, ie its not defaulted.

---

PS: To get the output you expect one does not need inheriting constructors (which is a feature that was only added in C++11), but you would write:

```
class B : A
{
public:
    B(int x) : A(x)
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor of B" << '\n';
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that makes sense. Do you know of any way I could achieve my expected behaviour in C++? Or should I write a separate post for that question, since that'd be a different topic.

Comment: @Horace its in the PS. I think you expect that `B` constructor is called first and then `A`s but thats wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I know about this feature and I understand that A is called first, then B. That's intuitive to me since B might depend on some of A's values. It's not quite what I'm looking for since if A had many more constructors all with different signatures, I'd need to write one of these for each. I was looking for a way to neatly have some code run after any of the available constructors of A.

Comment: @Horace in that case you can write a templated constructor of `B` that forwards all arguments to constructor of `A`

Comment: @Horace writing good questions is not easy. This isnt a bad one, but its not the one that helps you with your actual problem. No problem, just write another question ;)

Comment: @Horace perhaps something along the line of "How to make a single constructor of derived call different base class constructors, depending on what arguments are passed?"

Comment: Thank you, I might write the question but I think I've gotten enough leads in this one to figure it out, @NathanOliver in particular made a suggestion referencing what's called a "perfect forwarding constructor" and gave some sample code.

I think I'm on the right track with that info, I could google it and figure it out from here. If I don't somehow I'll write the question or see if someone else did.

Thanks!

Comment: @Horace I was in the mood. Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/q/77692843/4117728

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is reasonable based on the code you provided. However, the observed output is due to the fact that the constructor of the derived class B is still being called after the inherited constructor of A.

> B b(12);

creates an object of type B and calls the inherited constructor from A with the argument 12. This is why you see the output "Inside the constructor of A with one int argument."

After the base class constructor is called, the derived class constructor B() is called. In this case, it prints "Default constructor of B."

The inherited constructor from the base class is called first, followed by the execution of the derived class constructor.

If you want to achieve the output you expect, you might need to explicitly call the base class constructor in the initialization list of the derived class constructor. Here's an example:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::A;

    B() : A()  // Explicitly call the base class constructor
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor of B" << '\n';
    }
};
```

With this modification, the output should be as you expect.