# How to delegate to differnt constructor of a base class and call a derived class constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have this sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor of A" << '\n';
    }
    A(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Inside the constructor of A with one int argument" << '\n';
    }
    A(double i)
    {
        std::cout << "Inside the constructor of A with one double argument" << '\n';
    }
};

class B : A
{
    using A::A;
public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor of B" << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b(12);

    std::cout << "End of main";
}
```

And the output is :

```
Inside the constructor of A with one int argument
End of main
```

I understand why `B`s constructor is not called (see [Constructor inheritance in C++. Derived class's default constructor is not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77692594/4117728)) and I can write a `B(int)`, but the thing is that `A` has many constructors and when constructing a `B` I want the corresponding `A` constructor be called **and** one specific `B` constructor.

How can I achieve this without writing one `B` constructor for each `A` constructor?

In other words, I want output of `B b(12)` to be

```
Inside the constructor of A with one int argument
Default constructor of B
End of main
```

and also `B b(4.2)` to be

```
Inside the constructor of A with one double argument
Default constructor of B
End of main
```

without rewriting the constructor of `B` many times.

Comment: When `using A::A;` it is *as if* B's defaulted default constructor were called.  So in that regard, B's constructor is called.  If you want something more than that, you will need to write one B constructor for each A constructor.

Comment: @Eljay yes, but `B` constructor does more than what is shown here and I want that custom constructor be called without rewriting it for every `A` constrcutor

Comment: What you want is not what C++ provides.

Comment: @Eljay its a follow up of this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/77692594/4117728. The question isnt really about forwarding or inheriting constructors, they are only present because that was the initial approach of OP there. If you have some idea how to phrase the question better, feel free to edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I achieve this without writing one B constructor for each A constructor?

Instead of doing the work directly in `B`, you might add extra base/member which would do the job:

```
struct B_impl
{
    B_impl()
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor of B" << '\n'; // B_impl currently ;-)
    }
};
```

And then either

```
class B1 : A, B_impl
{
    using A::A;
};
```

or

```
class B2 : A
{
    using A::A;
    B_impl b_impl{};
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/46KzTY4zj)

Comment: Thanks Jarod, I'm actually defaulting to using your solution instead of Nathan's even though I marked his as the accepted answer. May I ask is this considered a 'technically works' kind of solution but if veterans were to read my code they'd think: what is this oddity, kind of looks like code smell. Or is this considered an ok thing to write.

I find this better than the templated forwarding constructor suggested by Nathan in the case when you want to have some well defined additional constructors. I keep having the templated constructor get called instead of my custom ones.

Comment: *" May I ask is this considered a 'technically works' kind of solution"* With proper naming ;-) I don't see any problem (some other stuff might go in `B_impl` to have logical component).

Comment: Thank you :- ). What do you mean by other stuff? Does the whole class_impl naming get used in some type of common architecture pattern that I might as well use if I'm gonna have 2 classes anyway?

Comment: "other stuff": I think about methods and/or members. In fact making `B_impl` a true/meaningful class (and so with a proper name). "impl" (or similar suffix) might be used in known pattern as pimpl idiom, for example. But "impl" would be a poor name if  it just handles constructors and not other methods.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was thinking. I was planning on this being there just for the functionality of adding extra code on top of inherited constructors. I wasn't thinking about adding any more 'stuff' to it. The dillema for me would be that I don't know why I would want to make it a meaningful class when all the functionality could be inside B instead. But at the same time I'm making this code for a personal project and don't want it to appear ugly to potential employers.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use a forwarding constructor in the derived class that forwards all parameters to the base class.  That would give you

```
class B : A
{
public:
    template <typename... Args> 
    B(Args&&... args) : A(std::forward<Args>(args)...) 
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor of B" << '\n';
    }
};
```

which when using

```
int main()
{
    B b(12);

    std::cout << "End of main";
}
```

outputs

```
Inside the constructor of A with one int argument
Default constructor of B
End of main
```

as seen in this [live example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/647787d35561936b).

---

This does come with a caveat that no implicit conversion happens with a template so if you try to use

```
B b({foo, bar, baz});
```

because `A` can be constructed with lets say a vector then this will fail to compile as `{foo, bar, baz}` has no type.

Comment: *"This does come with a caveat"* And also that default copy constructor is not selected for non-const reference...